# Выбрать из какого appsettings.json брать конфигурацию serilog

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core

Всем привет.

есть класс Program, есть настройки appsettings.Development.json и appsettings.Production.json. Не могу понять, как заставить брать конфигурацию, в зависимости от нашего запуска. И как вообще запускать приложение от Development или Production.

Т.Е необходимо разделить логику между Production и Development, но как между ними переключаться найти не могу.

Program.cs

```
using Serilog;

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
.WriteTo.Console()
.CreateLogger();

try
{
Log.Information("Starting the web host");
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Host.UseSerilog((context,services,configuration) => configuration
.ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration)
.ReadFrom.Services(services)
.Enrich.FromLogContext());

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();

// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
var app = builder.Build();


// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
Log.Fatal(ex, "Host terminated unexpectedly");
}
finally
{
Log.CloseAndFlush();
}

return 0;
```

appsettings.Development.json

```
{
"Serilog": {
"Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.File" ],
"MinimumLevel": "Debug",
"WriteTo": [
  {
    "Name": "Console"
  },
  {
    "Name": "File",
    "Args": { "path": "Logs/log.txt" }
  }
  ],
  "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId" ],
  "Properties": {
  "Application": "Sample"
  }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
  }
```

appsettings.Production.json

```
{
"Serilog": {
"Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.File" ],
"MinimumLevel": "Warning",
"WriteTo": [
  {
    "Name": "File",
    "Args": { "path": "Logs/log.txt" }
  }
  ],
  "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId" ],
  "Properties": {
  "Application": "Sample"
  }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
  }
```

Comment: ASP.NET Core настраивает поведение приложения в зависимости от среды выполнения с помощью переменной среды (**DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT** или **ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT** (если вызывается метод _WebApplication.CreateBuilder_ )).

Comment: Как на счёт использования условной компиляции, а именно директивы #IF(https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Друзья, все оказалось очень просто. В проекте идем в Properties->launchSettings.json и там в переменной "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" выбираем, какой из appsettings требуется использовать при запуске через IIS Express, Kestrel.
например:

```
 `"IIS Express": {
  "commandName": "IISExpress",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "swagger",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }`
```

ну и в зависимости от того, что у нас записано в переменной "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" идет автоматический поиск этого файла конфигурации в appsettings.json. Т.Е  "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development" будет искать appsettings.Development.json, если переменная "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production" будет искать appsettings.Production.json